# How to show pre checked checkboxes in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a problem
How do I show prechecked checkboxes in my android application.
Suppose there are 4 check boxes and I want to show 2 of them checked from the beginning based on a value 0 or 1 assigned to that display variable.
I am a very naive android developer.

Answer (score 47):

You can either use xml property

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    .... 
    android:checked="true"
/>
```

or set in your code like

```
boolean isChecked = ...;
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
cb1.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Comment: Will this applicable if app launches for first time??

Answer (score 9):

Vladimir's answer didn't work for me. Instead use this:

```
<CheckBox
...
android:state_checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set your value in

`checkBox.setTag("zero")` or

```
checkBox.setTag("one")
```

and check like this ...

```
String str = (String) checkBox.getTag();

if(str.equals("zero") || str.equals("one") ){
checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
```