# How to make check boxes checked by default?

Tags: android, json, checkbox

I have a json data from URL 1 which is a master. I load this in list view with check boxes and I get some other data from another URL 2 so now what the problem is I have to make check box values checked which are from URL 2 in URL 1 data.
So how can I achieve this

I will be thank full for your valuable response.

Comment: set check box true..

Comment: checkedTextView.setChecked(true);

Comment: @Destro i know it can be achieved by setting check box=true but how can check values from url1 and url2 and make the checked which are common

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. From XML:
   Add this to your `CheckBox` tag in XML `android:state_checked="true"` else if doesn't work then add this `android:checked="true"`
2. From Java: `YOUR_CHECKBOX_OBJECT.setChecked(true);`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501342/how-to-show-pre-checked-checkboxes-in-android)

PS: Next time search before you post a question.