# How to checkbox checked always even after app relaunch until user uncheck it in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, checked, unchecked

My question is simple i want to checked checkbox for always even app is closed and relaunch. This process should continue till user itself uncheck it. If user itself uncheck it then should be uncheck till user checked it again in android .

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: `public boolean isCheckBoxCheked=true;`. Default `checkboxObj.setEnable(isCheckBoxCheked);`. save the value in [SharedPreferance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity). when user uncheck the checkbox. make it `false` and again save it. Thanks Peace.

Comment: use PreferenceActivity. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity

Comment: check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501342/how-to-show-pre-checked-checkboxes-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this one simple code ......**

**Use `SharedPreferences` to maintain state of check boxes.**

**Initialization....**

```
checkBox.setChecked(getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("checkBox", true));
```

**OnCheckedChangeListener**

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("checkBox", isChecked).commit();

              }
        });
```

**First time all check boxes will be checked and it will be work like you want....**

Above code only for one check box. Try same for other check-boxes. Just change unique key for all check boxes like i used here **"checkbox"** in `checkBox.setChecked(getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("checkBox", true));`

**hope your work done by this.....**

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use `SharedPreferance` globally to store the default value of check box and change value inside the preference `onCheckChange` and when view load set state of checkbox according to flag in preferance

Answer (score 0):

keep a boolean flag in sharedPreferences or localDB for the user action. And by default keep this flag's value as true. When the user clicks checkbox, update this flag's value as well. So, whenever the application is launched, check this flag's value like:-

```
if(checkBoxEnabled) {
     checkBox.setEnabled(true);
} else {
     checkBox.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have added check box in xml layout, add `android:checked="true"` for initial check.

Add status to `SharedPreferences` when you listen a change in value. e.g. `onCheckedChanged()`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);

sp.edit.putBoolean("check_status", checkBox.isChecked()).apply();
```