# how to make a auto checked check box

Tags: java, android

How can I make an autochecked checkbox in java android?

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {

                if(isChecked){
                    bikesSelected.add(b.id);
                    checkBox.setSelected(true);
                    //to get checkbox if it has been checked
                    int checkBoxId = checkBox.getId();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , checkBox.getText().toString() + "-checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    bikesSelected.remove((Integer)b.id);
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8501342/9246764

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show pre checked checkboxes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501342/how-to-show-pre-checked-checkboxes-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If by auto-checked you mean by default selected, then that can be done in two ways

1. In layout xml, set android:**checked**="true"
2. Programmatically set **checkBox**.setChecked(true);

Comment: i tried but its not working, i actually wanna all my checkboxes to be autochecked, thanks btw